# Error: cannot declare variable ‘bg’ to be of abstract type ‘cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2’ in OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, opencv

I have recently installed OpenCv in my ubuntu 14.10 system and I was running a program and in fuction `cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` I am facing an error.

Error is `cannot declare variable ‘bg’ to be of abstract type ‘cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2’` Why I am facing this error

My code sample

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Mat frame;
    Mat back;
    Mat front;
    vector<pair<Point,double> > hand_middle;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg; //Here I am facing error
    bg.set("nmixtures",3);
    bg.set("detectShadows",false);
    //Rest of my code
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

the api changed in opencv3.0, you will have to use:

```
cv::Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> bg = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(...)
bg->setNMixtures(3);
bg->apply(img,mask);
```

Answer (score 1):

API in OpenCV 3.0 is now abstract.

```
cv::Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG2;
pMOG2 = cv::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
pMOG2->apply(frame, fgMaskMOG2);
```

Also Please fallow that link:
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html